# Python & Pandas: series to timedelta

Tags: python, pandas

M is a col in dataframe df which indicates the number of month.

```
M
1
0
15
```

I am trying to find the number of days between 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-01 + df.M. The following col is what i want to get.

```
daynum
31
0
456
```

I know how to do it by using loop and list:

```
int((datetime.strptime("2015-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") + relativedelta(months=df.M[i]) 
                    - datetime.strptime("2015-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")).days)
```

Is there any build-in function in pandas that can solve this problem easily?

Comment: Sorry are you trying to add months or days to `2015-01-01`?

Comment: For instance is this what you want: `In [41]:

pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01') + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['M'], unit='M')
Out[41]:
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-31 10:29:06', '2015-01-01 00:00:00',
               '2016-04-01 13:16:30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)`?

Comment: Thx! TimedeltaIndex is what i am looking for!

Comment: See my answer, Timedelta will *not* give the exact correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in the question, but using the automatic vectorized operations instead of looping.
First convert the series of integers to relativedelta's:

```
In [76]: M = pd.Series([1, 0, 15])

In [77]: M2 = M.apply(lambda x: dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=x))

In [78]: M2
Out[78]:
0              relativedelta(months=+1)
1                       relativedelta()
2    relativedelta(years=+1, months=+3)
dtype: object
```

Then you can do the same calculation:

```
In [80]: (pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') + M2) - pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01')
Out[80]:
0    31 days
1     0 days
2   456 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you want to have it as integer values instead of the timedelta as above, you can get this with `.dt.days`:

```
In [81]: days = (pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') + M2) - pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01')

In [82]: days.dt.days
Out[82]:
0     31
1      0
2    456
dtype: int64
```

---

**Reason to not use `Timedelta`**

In this case, you cannot work with a timedelta, as this does not exactly shift the date with a certain amount of months, but it appears to give you a certain kind of mean month length:

```
In [83]: pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='M')
Out[83]: Timedelta('30 days 10:29:06')

In [84]: (pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(M, unit='M')) - pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01')
Out[84]:
0    30 days 10:29:06
1     0 days 00:00:00
2   456 days 13:16:30
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

So this will give slightly different answers. For example in this case, it gives you 30 days instead of 31 for the first element.

The pandas equivalent to `relativedelta` would be to use a `DateOffset`. In this case eg `pd.DateOffset(months=1)`