# How to add weeks to a datetime column, depending on a django model/dictionary?

Tags: django, pandas

## Context

- There is a dataframe of customer invoices and their due dates.(Identified by customer code)
- Week(s) need to be added depending on customer code
- Model is created to persist the list of customers and week(s) to be added

### What is done so far:

#### Models.py

```
class BpShift(models.Model):
    bp_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    bp_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True, default='')
    weeks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

#### helper.py

```
from .models import BpShift
# used in views later
def week_shift(self, df):
        df['DueDateRange'] = df['DueDate'] + datetime.timedelta(
            weeks=BpShift.objects.get(pk=df['BpCode']).weeks)
```

I realised my understanding of Dataframes is seriously flawed.
df['A'] and df['B'] would return Series. Of course, timedelta wouldn't work like this(weeks=BpShift.objects.get(pk=df['BpCode']).weeks).

#### Dataframe

```
d = {'BpCode':['customer1','customer2'],'DueDate':['2020-05-30','2020-04-30']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

#### Customer List csv

BP Name,BP Code,Week(s)
Customer1,CA0023MY,1
Customer2,CA0064SG,1

#### Error

BpShift matching query does not exist.

#### Commentary

I used these methods in hope that I would be able to change the dataframe at once, instead of
using df.iterrows(). I have recently been avoiding for loops like a plague and wondering if this
is the "correct" mentality. Is there any recommended way of doing this? Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Can you include the dataframes as well?

Comment: Hi Jech, my bad! I've just included them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [Python & Pandas: series to timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35233251/383793) will help to take you from Series to timedelta. And although

```
pandas.Series(
    BpShift.objects.filter(
        pk__in=df['BpCode'].tolist()
    ).values_list('weeks', flat=True)
)
```

will give you a Series of integers, I doubt the order is the same as in df['BpCode']. Because it depends on the django Model and database backend.

So you might be better off to explicitly create not a Series, but a DataFrame with `pk` and `weeks` columns so you can use [df.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join). Something like this

```
pandas.DataFrame(
    BpShift.objects.filter(
        pk__in=df['BpCode'].tolist()
    ).values_list('pk', 'weeks'),
    columns=['BpCode', 'weeks'],
)
```

should give you a DataFrame that you can join with.

So combined this should be the gist of your code:

```
django_response = [('customer1', 1), ('customer2', '2')]

d = {'BpCode':['customer1','customer2'],'DueDate':['2020-05-30','2020-04-30']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index('BpCode').join(
    pd.DataFrame(django_response, columns=['BpCode', 'weeks']).set_index('BpCode')
)
df['DueDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DueDate'])
df['weeks'] = pd.to_numeric(df['weeks'])
df['new_duedate'] = df['DueDate'] + df['weeks'] * pd.Timedelta('1W')
print(df)
```

```
             DueDate  weeks new_duedate
BpCode                                 
customer1 2020-05-30      1  2020-06-06
customer2 2020-04-30      2  2020-05-14
```

You were right to want to avoid looping. This approach gets all the data in one SQL query from your Django model, by using `filter`. Then does a left join with the DataFrame you already have. Casts the dates and weeks to the right types and then computes a new due date using the whole columns instead of loops over them.

**NB** the left join will give NaN and NaT for customers that don't exist in your Django database. You can either avoid those rows by passing `how='inner'` to `df.join` or handle them whatever way you like.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the informative reply. Where can I find more information on "pk_in"?
Must have missed it in the documentation

Comment: Hi Chris, please ignore the above comment, it double underscored pk__in.

Comment: @hiayus Oh  yeah, sorry for the typo. It's should be mentioned in the doc for `filter`. (I copy pasted the typo to the second codeblock :) fixed the answer.

Comment: @hiayus I've updated the answer a bit to integrate the things.. Is this what you are after?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the edited response! I was lost when the join gave me an object and int64 error. This clears up a lot and is very educational. :D Leaving this here just in case others would like to understand the error as well! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795399/trouble-with-df-join-valueerror-you-are-trying-to-merge-on-object-and-int64